# Use secondary masterpage as default

Tags: sharepoint-designer, master-page, css, custom-masterpage

I am trying sharepoint in a small developing environment. 
I have a master frontpage that use a specific layout defined in a custom masterpage  (master-front.master). It look like this

```
| left box | content box | right box |
```

and that frontpage will have subsites that I want to use another custom masterpage  (master-main.master) that look like this:

```
| left box | content box |
```

But I cannot get it to work.

Under "Frontpage" I have a subsite called "Organization" where I have manually set the secondary masterpage. When I create i new subsite under "Frontpage" it gets the default sharepoint masterpage. But I want anything under "Frontpage" to use master-main.master.

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.. You're missing the whole concept of Master Pages and specifically Page Layout.

First of all, turn on Publishing Features.

Secondly, you dont really want to sepearte master pages, but you want 1 Master page with two different Page Layouts. Read more about the concept here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms543497(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Arh... thanks ... I have mistaken the whole concept. I am used to TYPO3. This is a but more complicated.

Comment: I hope you will help me answer this: 
If I am understanding you right, I will only need to create ONE masterpage and then X numbers of page layouts. Where the masterpage defines the global elements such as logo and top menu, and the page layout defines what I would call a Main Area?

Comment: Hi Morten. Yes, your understanding is 100% correct. A Master page is used to define the global look and feel including top navigation, left nav, styles, icons etc, and a Page layout is there to setup the different Web part zones. You can have two different page layouts for example with Layout 1 being a 3 column 2 rows layout and Layout 2 a 2 column setup. Hope that makes sense.